# Too many characters in character literal what is the error

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, database

Server Error in '/Purchase Order' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

Source Error:

```
Line 212:    <tr>
Line 213:    <td>
Line 214:        <asp:Button ID="Button1" value="Print" onclick="window.open('Default.aspx')" runat="server" Text="Button" />
Line 215:    </td>
Line 216:    </tr>
```

Comment: `Line 212: Line 213: Line 214: Line 215: Line 216: ` - doesn't mean anything without the code....

Comment: Show the lines where the error occur

Comment: asp:Button ID="Button1" value="Print" onclick="window.open('Default.aspx')" runat="server" Text="Button" />

Comment: no it does noot means in the code @NickR

Answer (score 5):

Since `Button1` is an ASP.NET button, you need to replace this:

```
onclick="window.open('Default.aspx')"
```

with this:

```
OnClientClick="window.open('Default.aspx')"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should onclientclick if you are trying to open a new page using  script

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" value="Print"  OnClientClick="window.open('Default.aspx')" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
onclick="window.location='Default.aspx'"
```

Replace this line from your code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" value="Print" onclick="window.open('Default.aspx')" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

with the following line.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" value="Print" onclick="window.location='Default.aspx'" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the HTML control if you don't want to call server function**

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="window.open('Default.aspx')" value="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

.net treats single quotes as chars - a single character.

Comment: add as comment otherwise